# Memory leak with DataTable and DataSource with polling

Tags: javascript, dom, yui, yui3

I have a `DataTable` which is populated from a remote JSON `DataSource`:

```
var dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({ source: url });

dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
    schema: {
        resultListLocator: "results",
        resultFields:  [ "field1", "field2" ]
    }
});

var table = new Y.DataTable({ columns = ["col1", "col2"] }

table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, { datasource: dataSource });

table.render("#table");

table.datasource.load({ request: query });
```

I'm trying to have the data in the table refreshed periodically.  [A forum poster recommended calling load periodically](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37037), which I've tried and it works as I was hoping for (data refreshes without displaying a Loading... message).

```
Y.later(1000/*ms*/, table.datasource, table.datasource.load, { request: query }, true);
```

However, I've noticed a memory leak in Chrome.  The table cells don't seem to be removed from memory.  Chrome's heap profiler is reporting lots of `HTMLTableCellElement` objects in `Detached DOM tree`.

Is this the best method of refreshing the data?  If so, is there some way to clear out the old table cells?

**Alternatives**

There is also the [`datatable-polling` module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datasource/datasource-polling.html) that can do periodic fetching of data.  I can't any examples of how this is supposed to be used with a YUI3 `DataTable` though.  However, [examples from YUI2](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~rdhyee/yui/examples/datatable/dt_polling.html) show you can do something the following, which appears to work:

```
dataSource.setInterval(1000,         
    {
        request: query,
        callback: 
            {
                success: function(e) { table.onDataReturnInitializeTable },
                failure: function() { Y.log("Polling failure", "error"); }
            }
    });
```

However, it looks like this is just what [`load` is doing under the hood anyway](http://yuiblog.com/sandbox/yui/3.3.0pr3/api/datatable-datasource.js.html):

```
load: function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    config.request = config.request || this.get("initialRequest");
    config.callback = config.callback || {
        success: Y.bind(this.onDataReturnInitializeTable, this),
        failure: Y.bind(this.onDataReturnInitializeTable, this),
        argument: this.get("host").get("state") //TODO
    };

    var ds = (config.datasource || this.get("datasource"));
    if(ds) {
        ds.sendRequest(config);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`datasource-polling` won't help you in this case because `Plugin.DataTableDataSource` doesn't make the DataTable listen to all changes in the DataSource. The most simple way of polling using `Plugin.DataTableDataSource` would be to set up the interval yourself like this:

```
var datasource = new Y.DataSource.IO(...);
var table = new Y.DataTable(...);

table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, {
  datasource: datasource
});

// call load() every second
var timer = Y.later(1000, table.datasource, 'load', {
  request: foo
}, true);

// later on, stop polling
timer.cancel();
```

The memory leak you mention is a possibility. DataTable is under ongoing development and it will get better at managing memory. However if you have a reproducible case and thorough measurements you should definitely [open an issue](https://github.com/yui/yui3/issues/new) at YUI's GitHub repository.

Comment: So, just to confirm, `load` should be responsible for cleaning up the memory used by the rows that are getting replaced?

Comment: Actually, `datatable.render` is responsible for that, and when you call `datatable.datasource.load`, `render` is called under the hood. So, yes.